# AutoHotKey: AltR + AltL + u does not work (but it works with a)

Tags: autohotkey, keymapping

Does anyone have a guess why the following AutoHotKey-Script is not working? Everything but the last 2 lines work perfectly fine but when I press AltR + AltL + u nothing happens.

```
!a::ä
!u::ü
!o::ö
!s::ß
<!>!a::Ä
<!>!u::Ü
<!>!o::Ö
```

I tried replacing "<!>!u::Ü" with things "RAlt & LAlt & u::Ü" but it had no result too.

btw:
<!>!x works for the following letters (and does not work for all others):
wrypafhklzxcvbnm